# Powerball Function issue in Python

Tags: python

My function stops working at the `if matches in ticket` line, immediately after the `matches` point, listing the error as invalid input. What is the reason for this, and how can I fix it? I'm very new to Python, so any help is very much appreciated. Additionally, this function is still a work in progress, and I recognize that it is currently highly inefficient, but I am attempting to fix this error before anything else is changed.

---

```
import random

def matches(ticket, winner): 
    score = 0
    attemptnum = 0
    for number in ticket:
    if number in winner:
        score += 1
    return score
def winner():
  win1 == rand.randint(1, 69)
  win2 == rand.randint(1, 69)
  win3 == rand.randint(1, 69)
  win4 == rand.randint(1, 69)
  win5 == rand.randint(1, 69)
  win6 == rand.randint(1, 69)
  winner == 'win1 win2 win3 win4 win5 win6'
def playPowerBall():
    print('Please select your first unique number between 1-69.')
    def ticket():
      num1 = int(input('1st Number:'))
      if num1 in winner():
        score += 1
        matches += 1
      else:
        score += 0 
        matches += 0
      num2 = int(input('2nd Number:'))
      if num2 in winner():
        score += 1
        matches += 1
      else:
        score += 0 
        matches += 0
      num3 = int(input('3rd Number:'))
       if num3 in winner():
        score += 1
        matches += 1
      else:
        score += 0 
        matches += 0
      num4 = int(input('4th Number:'))
      if num4 in winner():
        score += 1
        matches += 1
      else:
        score += 0 
        matches += 0
      num5 = int(input('5th Number:'))
      if num5 in winner():
        score += 1
        matches += 1
      else:
        score += 0 
        matches += 0
      num6 = int(input('6th Number:'))
      if num6 in winner():
        score += 1
        matches += 1
      else:
        score += 0 
        matches += 0
      attempts = num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6
    for matches in ticket:
      score += 1
    else:
      score += 0      
    if matches in ticket:
      print('You picked at least ' matches 'winning numbers in 6 attempts, please claim your cash prize.')
    else: 
      print('You do not have a winning combination. Would you like to play Powerball again?')
      response = str(raw_input('Y/N:')):
      if response == 'Y':
        os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, *sys.argv)
      else:
        print('Thank you for playing.')
        sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: This program won't run at all because its indentation is inconsistent. Please reproduce your indentation accurately. If readers have to try and guess your actual indentation, they may miss problems or introduce new ones into the program.

Comment: My apologies. I did need to alter the indentation when posting it here, and evidently I did some areas incorrectly, but in my editor all indentation is correct. The invalid input begins halfway through the said line, beginning at the s in matches. What is the reason for this and how should I fix it?

Comment: no reason to downvote his question. It is valid, but he needs to format the code better...

Comment: Indentation is still inconsistent. The program fails because of wrong indentation.

Comment: Either way, I know that in my code editor, the indentation is consistent and works perfectly well up until said point, which is stated not to be an indentation error, but an invalid input error.

Comment: Ok so you have answered your question. We cannot help anymore here since the code you published is wrong and you are not fixing it. Also you are doing a `for matches in ticket` Where are you defining `ticket`?

Comment: Yiekey: delete what you have now and paste your code again into the question. Select just the code, then press Ctrl+K **or** click the `{}` button in the toolbar. That should really be all you need to do. Well, that, and adding the exact error message. Do not paraphrase or cite or be tempted to copy "just the important bits" – we need to see as much as possible, so help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

Some things I am picking up as I am reading your code:

1. Your indentation is still all over the place, some places you use 2 spaces, others you use 4 - you **need** to fix this, python relies heavily on indentation to compile.
2. In your function `winner` you are not doing anything, the double equals sign is a [test operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) and will not do any assignment, it will simply *check* if the value in win1 is equal to the randomly generated number.
3. In the same function, you make a variable `winner` that holds a string with the characters `win1 win2 ...` in it, I can only assume you are trying to create an object that holds these win1 variables, for that you can use a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), like so:
   `winners = [win1, win2, win3, win4, win5, win6]`
4. In that same function you are not returning anything, so the function is useless, in order to *send* the output of the function back to what called it you must use `return(winners)`

I have no idea what you're trying to do in your largest `playPowerBall` function, so I will just discuss some things that are clearly confusing you:

5. `def` as a keyword *defines* a function, but does not execute it, you must call that function for it to run.
6. Like I said earlier, in order to send results out of a function you must *return* the answer/result.
7. I have a hunch that instead of seeing `invalid input` you are seeing an `invalid syntax` error because you are trying to check whether the integer `matches` is inside the function pointer `ticket`. This is not a valid syntax, to make a function call you must use parentheses otherwise python thinks you are referring to the function pointer, so `matches in ticket()` could be valid syntax, however as you have defined it I cannot see how that would work.

Has this code ever compiled properly or run at all? I think you need to go back to much more basic stuff about function definitions before trying to construct something this complex, start with one function definition and try and get that to work in a small program and then come back to this.

Let me know if there is anything else I can help with.